# Warped Table Top

Tags: desk

This is my first project.  I got the table top glued but then i believe, because of not clamping properly, i got a warp on one side in my board.

Please advise: If i try to screw the board to my base by force, *I.E. apply pressure on the board and  screw it to the base*, would that stay strong or is there an alternate way i can resolve the warp ?

Also would it help if i place a heavy weight on the warped side and clamp the other sides and leave it for a day.

[image: Side of Table that is fine]
[image: Warped Side Image 1]
[image: Warped Side Image 2]

Thanks
Raj

Comment: Have you tried screw that into something substantial and letting it works its way out?   Or have you tried wetting it and weighting it down?   Gravity usually works these things out.   Those are two quick methods I have used.   You could also just sit on the side that is bowed up for a couple weeks until it is even :)

Comment: I am thinking of trying to put a weight on the top but not sure of wetting would it affect my glue ?

Comment: by wetting is it soak it in water or just spray some water on top ?

Comment: I don't think the glue matters right?   Wet it - hose whatever.   Let it sit outside in the grass and sun concave side down.   Take a look every half hour.   This isn't about science - the wood will do what it wants.   This is more like throwing darts at a board while blindfolded.   If it get flat or close to flat, fasten it to something.   You biggest problem isn't flattening it, its that the light table structure underneath may not have the heft to keep this from bowing again.  Once it gets flatter you still need to hit it with a planer/sander.

Comment: Thanks mate will give it a try and sand it immediate once its flat..Hope my base keeps it from not bowing

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson , place that as an answer, I would elaborate how the choice of material is why the warping happened, not the clamping. Sanding the high spots and drawing down is the way to go. The joints look like saw teeth the way the twisted wood is  making the top act. As a cabinet maker friend of mine says "there is a flat top in there somewhere"

Comment: You could permanently bolt angle iron to the boards...on the underside of the table.

Answer (score 2):

DMoore is right in letting it sit outside on the grass will def. bow it as the wood absorbs moisture, but it'll probably go right back to where it was before when it dries.

If it were my project, I'd let it fully stabilize and work at flattening it. Plane or belt sander are good tools to use. To save work, maybe just get the worst of it flattened and then maybe your table frame could pull out the rest of the bow.

Looking at the growth rings, the OP made a classic beginners mistake. You should have alternated the orientation of the growth rings to reduce warping.   IE: one board's growth rings pointed up the next down, and so on.

Congratulations on getting into woodworking, but have patience because there's a learning curve there!

Comment: Good answer.   You have to at least try.   I would say I have done this method with a good 50 pieces of wood and been happy with 15-20.    All up to the wood gods.